# What can I do about an "Invalid sender" contract deployment error?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment, remix

When deploying a smart contract, I get this message: "Error: invalid sender undefined." See details below.  Why is this happening?  What do I need to do differently?

I wrote the smart contract below and compiled it on Remix online IDE([this](https://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.4.10+commit.f0d539ae.js)).

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is an password contract which included new,verify,delete,change password
// it also includes the user here.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
contract userPasswd
{
    mapping(bytes32 => bytes32) private  userPasswds ;
    event RecordReturnResult(bool res);

    /// @dev new the pair of user and password to the array here
    function newPair(string user, string password)  returns (bool) {      
        bytes32  sha3_user = sha3(user);
        bytes32  sha3_password = sha3(password);
        bool res = true;
        if (userPasswds[sha3_user] > 0) {
            res = false;
            RecordReturnResult(res);
            return res;
        }           
        else{
            userPasswds[sha3_user] = sha3_password;
            res = true;
            RecordReturnResult(res);
            return res;
        }      
    }

    /// @dev verify the pair of user and password stored in the blockchain
    function verify(string user, string password) returns (bool) {
        bytes32  sha3_user = sha3(user);
        bytes32  sha3_password = sha3(password);
        //userPasswd[sha3_user] = sha3_password;

        //check it
        if (userPasswds[sha3_user] == sha3_password){
            RecordReturnResult(true);
            return true;
        }           
        else{
            RecordReturnResult(false);
            return false;
        }
    }

     /// @dev delete the pair of user and password stored in the blockchain
    function del(string user) returns (bool) {
        bytes32  sha3_user = sha3(user);

        if (userPasswds[sha3_user] > 0){
           delete userPasswds[sha3_user];
           RecordReturnResult(true);
           return true;
        }
        else {
            RecordReturnResult(false);
            return false;   
        }

    }
      /// @dev change the pair of user and password stored in the blockchain
    function change(string user, string password) returns (bool) {
        bytes32  sha3_user = sha3(user);
        bytes32  sha3_password = sha3(password);

        if (userPasswds[sha3_user] > 0){
           userPasswds[sha3_user] = sha3_password;
           RecordReturnResult(true);
           return true;
        }
        else {
            RecordReturnResult(false);
            return false;
        }                
    }
}
```

After compiling in Remix, I copy the content of (the “Web3 deploy” text box) and paste it into the geth console. The content of the “Web3 deploy” text box is :

```
 var browser_queue_sol_queueContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"d","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addRequest","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"queueLength","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"popRequest","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_element","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ElementPopped","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_element","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_index","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ElementPushed","type":"event"}]);
var browser_queue_sol_queue = browser_queue_sol_queueContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '470000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

and the console shows:

```
Error: invalid sender undefined
undefined
```

the geth version is: Version: 1.6.6-unstable. go version is : go1.9beta2 windows/amd64

Comment: can you connect to your javascript console and type `eth.accounts`? Does it show a non-empty array? If it's empty you need to create (and fund) an account first: `geth account new` in your terminal.

Comment: yes, it does.> eth.accounts
["0x72b1897d547548148dae04813cb4920d3c66810f"], so what's your suggestion？ thank you.

Comment: alright, can you do `eth.getBalance('0x72b1897d547548148dae04813cb4920d3c66810f')` and see what it says? Also, log `web3.eth.accounts[0]` in the code to make sure web3 finds it.

Comment: > web3.eth.accounts[0]
"0x72b1897d547548148dae04813cb4920d3c66810f"

Comment: > eth.getBalance('0x72b1897d547548148dae04813cb4920d3c66810f')
2.575e+21

Comment: can you give me suggestion here? thank you very much.

Comment: is the account unlocked? Also, make sure your geth, web3 etc are up to date!

Comment: Hmm not sure. Just noticed your gas is only 470,000 though, can you add a zero

Comment: thank you. I have added a zero, but the result is the same: Error: invalid sender undefined
undefined

Comment: Please make sure your chainId is correct; if necessary you should be able to specify it in the parameter object

Comment: geth.exe --identity "helloworld"   --ws  --wsaddr 10.0.49.2 --wsport 8546 --wsorigins="*" --rpc  --rpcaddr 10.0.49.2 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*"   --datadir "C:\tools\src\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum\ethereum" --port 30303  --rpcapi "db,eth,net,ssh,miner,web3,personal,admin" --cache 2048 --networkid 88888 console                     it is command run geth.

Comment: {
"config": {
"chainId": 0,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0
},
"alloc" : {},
"coinbase" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"difficulty" : "0x1",
"extraData" : "",
"gasLimit" : "0x2fefd8",
"nonce" : "0x0000000000000042",
"mixhash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp" : "0x00"
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61977/discussion-between-jiebang-and-joel).

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13498/invalid-sender-error-on-private-chain