# Error: Returned error: invalid sender

Tags: web3js, transactions

I'm trying to sign transaction and send it to remote node, but I keep getting this error:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: invalid sender`

This is how I perform signing and then sending actions:

```
var Deployer = {
TxBuilder: function() {
    var signedTx;
    try{
        web3.eth.getTransactionCount(keyPair.address).then(function(res) {
            web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
                nonce: web3.utils.toHex(res + 1),
                from: keyPair.address,
                to: smartContractData.address,
                data: 'some encoded data here',
                gas: '4000000',
                gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex('5000000000'),
                gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex('4000000'),
                chainID: '2487'
            }, keyPair.privateKey).then(signedTx => {
                   //console.log(signedTx.rawTransaction);
                   web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction).on('receipt', console.log);
               });
        });
    } catch(error) {
        console.error('Error while sending signed tx: ' + error);
    }
}
```

};

Deployer.TxBuilder();

Here is account data, that I refer to in my code:

```
var keyPair = {
address: '0x413671Ef1633C4e31D07c4D36C92109792133C8a',
privateKey: ''
```

};

I'm able to sign the transaction, but I just can't send it, I tried what was described here: [Invalid sender error on private chain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13498/invalid-sender-error-on-private-chain)  but it didn't help as well.

I have balance in my account in custom ethers. I can deploy smart contracts and make calls / send transactions to any method in deployed smart contracts to the same private network from the very same account via MyEtherWallet, for instance. The problem is that I can't do it via web3.

I'm using:
- web3 1.0.0 36 beta

Any help with this is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What is the value of `keyPair.address`?

Comment: @goodvibration, it is a simple object with test keypair for private network deployed on a remote node. Value of the field is `0x413671Ef1633C4e31D07c4D36C92109792133C8a`

Comment: try to also add the parameter `v: 2487 * 2 + 35` to the tx to be signed.

Comment: @TudorConstantin thanks, tried that, but the error still remains the same

Comment: How did you configure the private network?

Comment: @goodvibration that was not me who configured it, but I'm sure it has some standard `genesis.json` with `chainID` set to 2487. I'm able to call another methods in other contracts using method signature. But I just wonder why I can't send signed transactions to the network. Do you think the problem could be in the configuration process? What exactly is on your mind?

Comment: In my mind, you should have something like `"accounts": {"0x413671Ef1633C4e31D07c4D36C92109792133C8a": {"balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"}}` in your genesis.json file.

Comment: @goodvibration but how will that make any difference? I have balance in my account in custom ethers. I can deploy smart contracts and make calls / send transactions to any method in deployed smart contracts to the same private network from the very same account via MyEtherWallet, for instance. The problem is that I can't do it via `web3`. If it is about `genesis.json`, then how come that MyEtherWallet manages to perform the actions?

Comment: have you tried prefixing the private key with `0x`?

Comment: @TudorConstantin: That was my original motivation in asking what is the value of `keyPair.address` (see the first comment in this thread). But according to the response, it is already prefixed with `0x`.

Comment: @TudorConstantin, yeah, tried that too, won't help, sender remains `invalid`, but thanks again, I appreciate the effort. (updated the question so that there is `0x` prefix for private key to prevent misleading thoughts about it)

Comment: BTW, you may as well replace `++res` with `res + 1`.

Comment: @goodvibration, is that a bad practice to do such increments as `++res` developing on top of ethereum?

Comment: IME, I got the _invalid sender_ error when the `v` value was wrong. What's even more confusing is that I had good transactions with `v: chainId`, with `v: 27` or `v: 28` and lately it seems that `v: chainId * 35 + 2` is the lucky variant. I suggest you to try them and see whether that wouldn't fix the issue.

Comment: @TudorConstantin, unfortunately, none of `v` values you've suggested helped

Comment: No, and it has nothing to do with Ethereum (you're not doing it "on top of ethereum", you're doing it in your off-chain code). Variable `res` is local. There's no point incrementing it if you're not using it anywhere else afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like an issue with version 2.0.0 of ethereumjs-tx:

```
https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx/issues/165 16
```

You will need to construct your transaction like below:

```
const tx = new Tx(txObject, {chain:'ropsten', hardfork: 'petersburg'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Shahid said, it has to do with an issue with 2.0.0 of ethereumjs-tx

Note that the hardfork property is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below

```
      const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;

      var rawTransaction = {
        "from": myAddress,
        "gasPrice": web3js.utils.toHex(20 * 1e9),
        "gasLimit": web3js.utils.toHex(210000),
        "to": contractAddress,
        "value": "0x0",
        "data": contract.methods.safeTransferFrom(myAddress, toAddress, tokenId).encodeABI(),
      }

        var privateKey = Buffer.from('abcde', 'hex')

        var transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction,{ chain: 'ropsten' , hardfork: 'petersburg' });

        transaction.sign(privateKey);

        web3js.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
            .on('transactionHash', console.log);
```

to the below

```
      const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;

      var rawTransaction = {
        "from": myAddress,
        "gasPrice": web3js.utils.toHex(20 * 1e9),
        "gasLimit": web3js.utils.toHex(210000),
        "to": contractAddress,
        "value": "0x0",
        "data": contract.methods.safeTransferFrom(myAddress, toAddress, tokenId).encodeABI(),
      }

        var privateKey ='abcde'

        web3js.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTransaction, privateKey)
        .then(function(value){
            web3js.eth.sendSignedTransaction(value.rawTransaction)
            .then(function(response){
              console.log("response:" + JSON.stringify(response, null, ' '));
            })
          })
```

`web3js.eth.accounts.signTransaction` will take the burden of including the correct chainId and nonce .
Reference: https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/1040